# Google Analytics data extraction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, spree, google-ads-api

I have an online store built using Rails and Spree.
While I am using the Google Analytics e-commerce tracker (analytics.js) for tracking conversions and other data, I would like to know whether a given conversion has come from either a paid ad, or an organic search, social networks, referrals, whatever.

Is is possible to dynamically extract this kind of info from Google?

How could I set this up? Any useful pointers on this?

Comment: Google Analytics Core reporting API (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/). Information on traffic sources is available via the medium/source/campaignname fields (Field names are listed here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)